# Splitting an ajax get payload

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I am having a pretty big amount of data by my standards (200 rows of data) and to load all of them at once is taking a while and most users are not digging my 'loading the awesome' thing i have going on in my table which takes around 5 or more seconds.

I have looked around for a solution and found datatable's deferred rendering http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/ajax/defer_render.html

Problem is i do not know how it exactly works(but i think datatables is loading more records in response to a user action.i.e scrolling). My idea of loading the 200 rows is to first load the first 10 records and then silently load 10 records at each go until the entire 200 records are loaded.

Is it possible to split the data this way?.

Comment: Five seconds! FFS, tell the impatient little so-and-sos that when Beetroot was at University, he would walk a round trip of 2 miles to the Computing Centre at the other end of Campus to drop off his coding sheet and a stack of Hollerith cards, then walk the same round trip the following day to pick up the results - typically a compilation failure ... Five seconds!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have the right idea (that you need to have less data get sent in one go so that it will load faster), but I think you should look at limiting it from the server side until it is needed instead of trying to defer it, like it talks about here:

http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/server_side.html